# How to grant access of a file out of sandboxed macOS app in Swift5?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm experiencing `launch path not accessible` error by run a shell script in sandboxed macOS app via Process().

First, entitlements file:

```xml
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
```

All code show on below:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button("grant access") {
        chooseFile()
      }
    }
  }
  
  func chooseFile() {
    print(">>>>>>>> choose file start")
    let dialog = NSOpenPanel()
    
    dialog.title = "grant access"
    dialog.canChooseFiles = true
    
    print(">>>>>>>> opening dialog")
    if dialog.runModal() == .OK {
      if let filePath = dialog.url {
        print(">>>>>>>> selected file: \(filePath.path)")
        grantAccess(url: filePath)
        exec(url: filePath)
      }
    }
  }
  
  func grantAccess(url: URL) {
    do {
      let data = try url.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
      UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "bookmarkKey")
      print(">>>>>>>> grant access success")
    } catch {
      print(">>>>>>>> grant access failed: \(error)")
    }
  }
  
  func exec(url: URL) {
    
    if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
      print(">>>>>>>> url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource: true")
    } else {
      print(">>>>>>>> url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource: false")
    }

    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()
    let launchPath = url.path()
    print(">>>>>>>> launchPath: \(launchPath)")
    
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launchPath = launchPath
    
    print(">>>>>>>> before task.launch()")
    task.launch()
    print(">>>>>>>> after task.launch()")
    
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
      print(output)
    }
    
    url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
  }
}
```

output:

```
2023-05-18 18:10:08.646588+0800 GrantAccess[79410:26642970] Metal API Validation Enabled
>>>>>>>> choose file start
>>>>>>>> opening dialog
2023-05-18 18:10:09.562084+0800 GrantAccess[79410:26642970] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
>>>>>>>> selected file: /Users/archcst/Desktop/sh.sh
2023-05-18 18:10:10.946571+0800 GrantAccess[79410:26642970] [logging] open flag(s) 0x01000000 are reserved for VFS use and do not affect behaviour when passed to sqlite3_open_v2
2023-05-18 18:10:10.946685+0800 GrantAccess[79410:26642970] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 46922 of [554764a6e7]
2023-05-18 18:10:10.946715+0800 GrantAccess[79410:26642970] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:46922: (0) open(/private/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - Undefined error: 0
>>>>>>>> grant access success
>>>>>>>> url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource: true
>>>>>>>> launchPath: /Users/archcst/Desktop/sh.sh
>>>>>>>> before task.launch()
2023-05-18 18:10:10.953065+0800 GrantAccess[79410:26642970] [General] launch path not accessible
2023-05-18 18:10:10.956572+0800 GrantAccess[79410:26642970] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000190d4b19c __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019086a4d4 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   Foundation                          0x0000000191cb6294 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 4036
    3   GrantAccess                         0x00000001046d9c60 $s11GrantAccess11ContentViewV4exec3urly10Foundation3URLV_tF + 1584
    4   GrantAccess                         0x00000001046d8b70 $s11GrantAccess11ContentViewV10chooseFileyyF + 1908
    5   GrantAccess                         0x00000001046d83f4 $s11GrantAccess11ContentViewV4bodyQrvg7SwiftUI6ButtonVyAE4TextVGyXEfU_yycfU_ + 12
    6   SwiftUI                             0x00000001b9905dd8 block_destroy_helper + 1276
    7   SwiftUI                             0x00000001b990416c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 23992
    8   SwiftUI                             0x00000001b99041d0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 24092
    9   AppKit                              0x0000000194097a50 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 440
    10  AppKit                              0x0000000194097868 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 72
    11  AppKit                              0x00000001940977ac __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 100
    12  AppKit                              0x00000001940976d4 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 204
    13  AppKit                              0x00000001940975f8 -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 88
    14  AppKit                              0x0000000194094bfc NSControlTrackMouse + 1480
    15  AppKit                              0x0000000194094608 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 144
    16  AppKit                              0x00000001940944c0 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 488
    17  AppKit                              0x000000019409398c -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 448
    18  AppKit                              0x0000000194092474 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 3476
    19  AppKit                              0x000000019401d0dc -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 364
    20  AppKit                              0x000000019401cd9c -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 284
    21  AppKit                              0x000000019401c0e0 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1556
    22  AppKit                              0x000000019426c0f0 -[NSApplication _handleEvent:] + 60
    23  AppKit                              0x0000000193ee357c -[NSApplication run] + 500
    24  AppKit                              0x0000000193eba9a8 NSApplicationMain + 880
    25  SwiftUI                             0x00000001b8f1d974 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 8272
    26  SwiftUI                             0x00000001ba07cfa0 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_14 + 188
    27  SwiftUI                             0x00000001b98fe43c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 136
    28  GrantAccess                         0x00000001046dad5c $s11GrantAccess0aB3AppV5$mainyyFZ + 40
    29  GrantAccess                         0x00000001046dae08 main + 12
    30  dyld                                0x000000019089bf28 start + 2236
)
```

It's seems I've abtained the access of the script, but still couldn't run it. However, if set app-sandbox to false, these code works fine:

```
2023-05-19 09:52:26.113632+0800 GrantAccess[93821:27259040] Metal API Validation Enabled
>>>>>>>> choose file start
>>>>>>>> opening dialog
2023-05-19 09:52:27.020965+0800 GrantAccess[93821:27259040] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2023-05-19 09:52:28.211853+0800 GrantAccess[93821:27259040] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2023-05-19 09:52:29.027746+0800 GrantAccess[93821:27259040] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
>>>>>>>> selected file: /Users/archcst/Desktop/sh.sh
2023-05-19 09:52:30.820140+0800 GrantAccess[93821:27259040] [logging] open flag(s) 0x01000000 are reserved for VFS use and do not affect behaviour when passed to sqlite3_open_v2
2023-05-19 09:52:30.820273+0800 GrantAccess[93821:27259040] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 46922 of [554764a6e7]
2023-05-19 09:52:30.820306+0800 GrantAccess[93821:27259040] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:46922: (0) open(/private/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - Undefined error: 0
>>>>>>>> grant access success
>>>>>>>> url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource: true
>>>>>>>> launchPath: /Users/archcst/Desktop/sh.sh
>>>>>>>> before task.launch()
>>>>>>>> after task.launch()
hello world
```

As App Store requires all app should be sandboxed, I've tried several days but can't find where's the problem. Any hints?

Comment: Not sure here but when you launch a process you start that process without inheriting any privileges or access rights from your current (app) process. So calling startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() on the url will have no effect. At least that is how I believe it works.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Your comment worth a try, is there any instructions about privileges of process()?